# snapshot.hasData return an empty array

Tags: android, api, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the data to display in List view but unfortunately i'm facing the error as the snapshot return empty values

Below is the code for my API

```
 static Future<List<Permission>> getPermissionData() async {
    String ruhusa = 'permission';
    var response = await http.get(mainUrl + ruhusa,
          headers: setHeader(accessKey.accessKey));

      List<Permission> permissions = [];
      if(response.statusCode == 200){

        print(response.statusCode);

        Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // print(response.body);
        for(var item in body['msg']){
          Permission permission = Permission.fromJson(item);
          permissions.add(permission);
          // return permissions; 
        }
        return permissions;
      }  
      // print(permissions); 
      return permissions; 

  }
```

This is the code where i want to display using future builder

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
        future: PermissionService.getPermissionData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Permission>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot != null) {
              print("This is ${snapshot.data}");
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, permissionSpecificRoute,
                          arguments: snapshot.data[index]);
                    },
                    child: PermissionCard(
                      permission: snapshot.data[index],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
               return Center(child: Text("Oops error issues is ${snapshot.hasError}"));
            }
            else {
              return Center(child: Text('No permissions requested'));
            }
          } else {
            return PageLoader();
          }
        },
      ),
```

When I try to print it in my console it return

This is []

Anyone who can help please what should i do to make the snapshot receive the real data

Comment: What is the value of this print `print(response.body);` ?

Comment: it return the response from API, means i'm getting the response

Comment: Be sure ```Permission.fromJson(item)``` is working fine, try to debug it and see, probably there is a parsing error so an empty array is returned (because you already initialized it as an empty array)

Comment: Are you sure your for loop `for(var item in body['msg']){` is working ?

Comment: i'm trying to print whatever is inside the for(..) but i'm getting nothing

Comment: wrap your for loop with try catch and check the error in catch clause

Comment: ok let me try to do that

Comment: i've tried try catch my for loop but still i'm getting nothing

Comment: what can be another good options instead of using for loop there? @ikerfah

Comment: in try catch now i'm getting the response when i print permissions i get the response [Instance of permission]

Comment: Put you json response and Permission class with fromJson

Comment: sorry i didn't get you clearly, can you please provide just a one line of code on how should i do what you are saying??@ikerfah

Comment: i mean update your posts with you  json response (from the server) and your ```Permission``` class code